# Foundation 2010 Install Requires Server 2008 SP 2 on Windows 10

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I'm trying to install SharePoint Foundation 2010 on my Windows 10 machine.  I'm getting the following error on Install:

> Setup is unable to proceed due to the following error(s): This product
>   requires Windows Server 2008 Service Pack 2 or above.  Correct the
>   issue(s) listed above and re-run setp.

But... I'm on Windows 10.  When I download Server 2008 SP2 and try to install it, it tells me I'm on the wrong version of Windows (duh).  So, why is SP Foundation 2010 telling me I need a SP that isn't compatible with my version of Windows?  How the eff do I get Foundation 2010 installed?

Comment: SharePoint 2010 being installable on Windows 7 was kind of a fluke. It was a useful fluke, since Windows 7 doesn't support Hyper-V, and most people who wanted to do development on client computers were running Windows 7 at the time. But it meant putting your poor Windows 7 box through all sorts of misery and torment as it ran all of SharePoint's web, database, and timer services. Fortunately Windows 10 professional comes with Hyper-V, so you can just spin up a VM if needed to emulate a SharePoint environment. You might want to check out Docker to make managing VMs easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint installation on windows 10 is not supported. As per my experince and best practice, you need to follow these steps

- Create a Hyper-V on your windows 10 machine
- Install Windows Server 2008 r2 or what ever server version you want to install
- Now you install the SPF 2010 on that virtual Machine.

[check this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee554869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: That's ridiculous.  I can't believe SharePoint isn't installable on Windows 10.  Sometimes I wonder what the hell they're thinking over at MS.